# Do I have to put ,Inc. every time I mention our company in a single article?

Tags: phrase-usage, formality, abbreviations, business-language

I write blogs for our company website, often commenting on what services our company provides, so I will usually mention our company name a few times in the article. It is a local company, but it is incorporated and the official name of the company includes ",Inc." at the end.

I always include the full name of the company in the first instance in an article, but because our full name is a bit long, I've been shortening it in the rest of the article. Is that bad grammar or improper etiquette?

Example: if our full name is "A-1 Safety & Training, Inc." can I say the full name once at the beginning of the article and then just say "A-1 Safety" in the rest of the article or should I use the full name in every instance? What is proper?

Comment: Does your company have an in-house style guide for publications? Who is the intended audience for your blog?

Comment: It is unclear what makes you think that such shortening would be 'bad grammar or improper etiquette'.

Comment: There may be legal requirements that transcend English style guidance (as for instance with trademarks). ELU does not advise on legal matters.

Comment: A legal document might *define* its terms: "the company" shall mean "A-1 Safety & Training, Inc." But as your blog is on the company website, isn't "we" sufficient? A blog isn't a formal document.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to call it **A-1** but use a style/colour close to the corporate style.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick responses. There wasn't anything listed specifically in our style guide about it. One of my bosses was asking why I didn't include it all the time and the other boss was saying that it wasn't legally necessary for every instance, since the "Inc." is part of our actual logo on everything. I just wanted to see here if there was any grammar or usage styling that is proper for it to help settle the discrepancy. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone noted in the comments, this is a question of style, not grammar. I will here reproduce the recommendations of two influential style manuals: *The Chicago Manual of Style* (CMoS, 17th ed.) and *The AP Stylebook* (2019).

**CMoS**

> **10.24: Abbreviations and ampersands in company names**
>
> Abbreviations and ampersands are appropriate in notes, bibliographies, tabular matter, and the like. See also 14.135.
>
> > Ginn & Co.
> > JPMorgan Chase & Co.
> > Moss Bros.
> > RAND Corp.
>
> In running text, company names are best given in their full forms. It should be noted, however, that some full forms include ampersands and abbreviations. If in doubt, especially with reference to contemporary firms, look up the company name at a corporate website or other authoritative source. Such elements as *Inc., & Co.,* and *LLC* may be omitted unless relevant to the context.
>
> > Johnson & Johnson was founded in 1886.
> > JPMorgan Chase operates in more than sixty countries.
> > AT&T Corporation was once known as the American Telephone and Telegraph Company.

***AP Stylebook***

> **company names**
>
> … You must include the full company name somewhere in the story. This ensures
> the story will be among the search results on major websites.
>
> The formal name need not be used on first reference — for example, ***Costco*** is
> acceptable for ***Costco Wholesale Corp.*** — but it should be contained in the body
> of any story in which the subject matter could affect a company’s business.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from rules of grammar or personal preference, state laws also dictate the use of Inc. or other corporate identification. Using the correct company name is part of securing the legal protection of your incorporated legal status. I would say use it at least once per article.

Comment: Hello, Aaron. Sound advice, but ELU steers clear of advising about legal communication requirements. It's an area not always closely related to standard usage ... and could result in exposure to damages claims. But you're safe with your 'take care'.